# How do I label the solution of a word problem using matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices

The table on the left gives the birth and death rates (per million) by region. The table on the right gives the populations (in millions) in each region for a number of years. Use matrix multiplication to get a matrix showing the total number of births and deaths in each year.
                Births          Deaths
Africa          .036             .014
Asia            .019             .008
Latin America   .021             .006
North America   .014             .008
Europe          .011             .011 years   Africa  Asia    L.America  N.America  Europe
                                      1960    283    1628      218       199         425
                                      2002    839    3518      539       320         513

Thank you

Comment: If this is homework, please label it as homework. Even if it is not, it is highly impolite to post giving orders (your post is written in the imperative); if you have a question then *ask* a question, don't give commands. And in your haste to copy the text of the assignment, you failed to format it, so that there is *no* "table on the right" and no "table on the left".

Comment: As Arturo said, I don't see any tables and I don't know what you are asking.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Didn't notice there were several years on the "table".

Suppose there are $R$ regions (in your case, $R = 5$) and $Y$ years (in your case, $Y = 2$). You have an $R \times 2$ matrix $A_{rs}$, where $A_{r1}$ is the birth rate in region $r$, and $A_{r2}$ is the death rate. You also have the region population $Y \times R$ matrix $B_{yr}$, which represents the population of region $r$ at year $y$. You want the total number of deaths and births for each year. This is a summation over the different regions of something, which corresponds to a multiplication of the two matrices (perhaps transposed).

Where are you stuck?

Comment: Not sure how to label the solution. Columns represent what and rows represent what?

Comment: One of them will represent the year, the other will represent a statistic, i.e. births or deaths. Which is which depends on you - tabular data can always be presented in two ways (this corresponds to transposing the matrix).